# C++ Infinite while loop if given wrong type for condition

Tags: c++, while-loop

[UPDATED] I have the following code in C++ (skipping the non-necessary details):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    double value;
    double sum = 0;
    double max, min;
    string msg = "Enter next value (-1) to end: ";
    int validCounter = 0;

do{
    cout << msg;
    cin >> value;  // Values assumed to be numbers
}
while (value <= 0 and value != -1);

if (value > 0.0){sum+= value, max = value, min = value, validCounter = 1;}  // Initial values of min, max, validCounter = 1
while (value != -1){
    cout << msg;
    cin >> value;

    // Only take positive values into consideration for stats
    if (value > 0) {
        validCounter++;
        sum += value;
        if (value > max) { max = value; }
        if (value < min) { min = value; }
    }
}
cout << to_string(validCounter) + " valid value(s) entered" << endl;
if (validCounter > 0){
    cout << "Minimum: " + to_string(min) << endl;
    cout << "Maximum: " + to_string(max) << endl;
    cout << "Moyenne: " + to_string(sum/validCounter) << endl;
}

return 0;
```

}

However when prompted to enter a value (supposed to be a number for simplicity, this is a beginners program) if the value entered is not a double the while loop starts to display the input prompt infinitely. Why is this? Is it due to the fact that comparing String != -1 (or any other non int/double type) causing the loop to reiterate? I am quite confused here.

Comment: How do you initialise `value`?

Comment: Please update your question to show the declaration of `value`. This *is* a necessary detail. Also a declaration of `msg` would be useful.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the user types a non-number?

Comment: Some handling such as isdigit() for the input is recommended. You can then cast the value to a double/float for more correctness.

Comment: @quamrana question updated, hope it's clearer now

Comment: @A.D you need to clear the error to be able to read again, then to bypass the wrong input, look at my answer

Comment: The reason why it prints the message infinitely is because if you try to read a number, it reads as many characters as it can while still making sense. So when it finds something that's can't be in the number, it stops. So if the first character already can't be in a number, it's going to stop without taking anything from `cin`. As a result, it's going to run infinitely because `cin >> value;` is never taking anything from `cin` and `(value <= 0 and value != -1)` is never going to be `true`.

Comment: Just a minor point about how to think about formatted input: "if the value entered is not a double" conflates two steps. The user does **not** enter a **value**; they enter **text**. The stream extractor **converts** that text to a value if it can. So the problem is more accurately phrased "if the text entered cannot be converted to a double". Sometimes the solution is to separate those steps, i.e., read the text into a string and convert it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace

```
do{
    cout << msg;
    cin >> value;  // Values assumed to be numbers
}
while (value <= 0 and value != -1);
```

by

```
do {
  cout << msg;
  if (!(cin >> value)) {
    string dummy;

    cin.clear();   // to be able to read double
    cin >> dummy; // to remove the non float
    value = 0;
  }
  while (value <= 0 and value != -1);
```

you need to clear the error to be able to read again, then to bypass the wrong input, may be you can also just read a character, decide what to do in case of an error

Example :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double value;

  do {
    cout << "value please" << endl;
    if (!(cin >> value)) {
      string dummy;

      cin.clear();
      cin >> dummy;
      value = 0;
    }
  } while (value <= 0 and value != -1);

  cout << "valid double :" << value << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
% ./a.out
value please
aze
value please
-12
value please
12
valid double :12
```

Comment: So if I understand this correctly: if the value cannot be put into a double you clear the errors and put it in a dummy string ?

Comment: yes, you can also just read a character rather than a 'word' but you risk to write a lot of time the message.

Comment: Okay :) Just a last question: is this the standard way of doing things in C++? I am quite new to this language and this way of going about it seems quite weird to me.